# Axis Color of Date Histogram in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have successfullly created a histogram using a date field.

```
hist(df.sat$created_at, breaks="hours", freq=T, xlab="Time", 
  main="Sat  Volume")
```

My issue is that when I attempt to fill in the bars using `col="red"` both the bars and both the x/y axes change to red, when I only want the bars.  What is the best way way only fill in the bars?

[image]

Here are some data:

```
    > dput(df.sat$created_at[sample(c(1:9000), 50)])
structure(list(sec = c(41, 3, 13, 11, 49, 55, 19, 21, 6, 15, 
54, 45, 45, 39, 50, 27, 35, 25, 22, 35, 42, 31, 45, 29, 1, 3, 
8, 47, 38, 2, 13, 29, 34, 42, 15, 19, 3, 39, 41, 12, 34, 50, 
15, 27, 0, 29, 47, 26, 21, 5), min = c(46L, 38L, 4L, 35L, 26L, 
56L, 9L, 52L, 51L, 15L, 49L, 3L, 41L, 59L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 53L, 
25L, 51L, 23L, 38L, 30L, 3L, 43L, 33L, 36L, 52L, 0L, 21L, 27L, 
22L, 51L, 31L, 0L, 37L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 3L, 45L, 13L, 59L, 10L, 
11L, 7L, 41L, 21L, 5L, 20L), hour = c(14L, 16L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 15L, 18L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 17L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 20L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 15L, 
17L, 17L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 17L), mday = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), mon = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), year = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L), wday = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), yday = c(98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 
98L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", 
"mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = c("America/New_York", "EST", "EDT"))
```

Comment: Interesting, I don't think this is intended behaviour...

Comment: @Joris I think it is, because `?hist` tells us where `...` is passed on to, and `axis()` takes a `col` argument as a graphical parameter. I see this as more of an issue of providing high level plotting code that is too flexible. These things are tricky to get right when you want to pass in extra plotting args/pars.

Comment: @Gavin : I didn't say it is unexplainable behaviour, but I can't possibly imagine that it's a conscious choice to make the axis color the same as the fill color in `hist()` And actually, I didn't notice that before...

Comment: @Joris I know, but the code and the docs are pretty clear one where the `...` go. So what @Bitbert3 is seeing is a _consequence_ of intended behaviour. This whole passing of graphical pars on to a range of plotting functions is one of the things in R I'd change if I could. There are lots of hack workarounds in base R code and packages I contribute to, to allow these sorts of uses work without the sort of side effects observed here, but they pollute the code a great deal.

Comment: Actually it seems this might be unintended - but is really a clash between the POSIXt method for `hist()` and the plotting code used.

Comment: I agree that I think it is unintended behaviour.  Compare:

hist(runif(100), col="blue")

with 

     random.dates <- as.Date("2001/1/1") + 70*stats::runif(100); hist(random.dates, "weeks", format = "%d %b", col="blue")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to get around it a bit by plotting the histogram first and the axes later :

```
hist(Data, breaks="hours", freq=T, xlab="Time", col="red",
  main="Sat  Volume",axes=F)
Axis(Data,col="black",side=1)
axis(2,col="black")
```

Reason to use the generic `Axis()`, is that it takes into account that your variable is a TimeDate class. The default `axis()` doesnt.

---

EDIT :

FYI, this behaviour is only to be seen with histograms where `DateTime` classes are used on the X axis. The default `hist()` function doesn't change the color of the axis when using a fill color for the bars.

Answer (score 4):

Plot the histogram without axes and then add them in later:

```
hist(dat, breaks="hours", freq=TRUE, col = "red", axes = FALSE)
axis.POSIXct(side = 1, dat)
axis(2)
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: or use the S3 generic `Axis()` as per @Joris' answer. I prefer @Joris' suggestion as you don't need to care what class the data are in!